# TFS xamarin build tasks steps

Tags: git, tfs

I'm looking to extend some post build tasks to build my xamarin application, using TFS 2017 and Git, but i'am so confused in the step

could you help me to make a build job for my application ?

EIDT :

This the build who i do it

but is not working

[details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUpPG.png)

EDIT 2:

The current android sdk installed is 25, how i can update them ?

Comment: What did you try to do?

Comment: I try to make a Build Definitions for deploy my xamarin application

Comment: What did you put in the definition? where you got an error?

Comment: the error in : Générer le projet Xamarin.Android 

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(647,2): Error XA5207: Could not find android.jar for API Level 27. This means the Android SDK platform for API Level 27 is not installed. Either install it in the Android SDK Manager (Tools > Open Android SDK Manager...), or change your Xamarin.Android project to target an API version that is installed. (C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-27\android.jar missing.)

Comment: Have you installed this ? you can install this on your build server from your visualstudioinstaller, select 'Android SDK-Setup (API-Level 27)'

Comment: i can't install android sdk  27 , visuel studio don't show any upgrade/update after install xamarin
also, i can't open android sdk manager , visual studio show android sdk manager is need to be updated and don't give me the link to do